Finding the tangent lines to an ellipse which pass through a point not on the graph
I am struggling to find the tangent lines to the parabola $x^2 + 9y^2 = 36$ which pass through the point $(12,2)$ not on the graph.
I've already found one tangent line, that being $y = 2$, because the maximum y-value of the graph is 2 and so it would be a horizontal line.
My issue comes in finding the second tangent line: I understand that I have to implicitly differentiate for $y' = \frac{-x}{9y}$ and then make it equal to $m = \frac{y-2}{x-12}$, but here is where my understanding stops.
I don't know how I could continue to solve past $9y(y-2) = -x(x-12)$ to find the tangent line.
Any help is appreciated, thank you!

$(x^2+9y^2-36)(12^2+9\cdot 2^2-36)-(12x+9\cdot 2y-36)^2= -108 (y - 2) (4 x - 9 y - 30) $
